# What are compiled to classes in Play framework target directory?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have two target directories in my play framework project.

one is the target directory in project(source root) directory

and the other is just target directory in my play framework project(same level with app,conf,log,project,public...).

I want to know

1)what is the difference between project(source root).target and the other one.

2)and why I need to have two of them, not one.

3)and finally, What are compiled to classes in Play framework target directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it is all about sbt's recursive architecture. As mentioned [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Full-Def.html#sbt-is-recursive)

> The project directory is another project inside your project which knows how to build your project.

So this means, project/target is the target directory for the "project" project which is responsible for building your real(play in here) project.

1) root target is your play project's target and project/target is target of your project at project directory.

2) Because project/ is a different project from yours, it have to be compiled to compile your project.

3) Check [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Anatomy#The-target/-directory) for details but basicly it contains pretty everything required

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, It was very helpful! :)